# Результат запроса Ajax+mysql+javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Всем привет! Прошу помощи.
Есть следующее в scripts.js:

```
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "Makers_details.php",             
        data:{
            username: $("#username").val(),          
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#but3").html(data);               
            }  
        });
```

в php файле собственно запрос в бд и формирование ответа в html. Вот код:

```
<?php   

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
    or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('stepbystep') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');
    // Выполняем SQL-запрос
    $query = "SELECT * FROM firm where Name like '%".$_REQUEST['username']."%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

    // Выводим результаты в html
    echo "<table id='mytable'>\n";
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";

    $lat=$row['lat'];
    $lng=$row['lng'];
    $rows[] = $line;

    }
    echo "</table>\n";
    return $result;
    ?>
```

Собственно все работает - в #but3 выводится результат запроса из бд. Но я никак не могу понять как мне продолжить работать в ajax (сразу после строчки $("#but3").html(data); ) с результатом запроса... То есть я впихнул результат в #but3, но дальше хочу в цикле работать с результатом запроса... Т.е. результат же представляет грубо говоря таблицу, вот мне нужно по этой таблице пробежать и получить данные из каждой ячейки и скажем тот же их записать еще раз в #but4 например

Comment: Вам нужно к `data` применить любой цикл, например `each` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Почти подходит... Но не пойму как там обращаться к строкам и ячейкам...

Comment: И мне кажется что все-таки он бежит не по строкам и столбцам а по каждому символу результата...((((

Comment: Покажите пример ответа

Comment: jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    alert(i, val);

Comment: Это циклит вывод сообщения навсегда...

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу содержимое переменной `data`

Comment: Я обращаюсь к data - но я правильно понимаю что это уже просто текст html... В php файле есть переменная $result, можно както по ее элементам в javascripte пробежать????

Comment: Если эта переменная передается в js, то можно

Comment: Ну подскажите же как этот цикл написать...

Comment: А что нужно получить в итоге, т.е. зачем бежать по ячейчкам?

Comment: Пробежаться по ячейкам можно, например, так: var td = $("#but3").find('td'), str = ''; if ($(td).size()>0) for (var i = 0; i < $(td).size(); i++) str += $(td).eq(i).html()+', ';

Comment: Ajax передает данные на сервер (в php файл) и получает от него ответ в виде html, тут же записывает этот ответ в #but3 в разделе success. Сервер формируя ответ делает запрос к БД и получает из БД данные. Вот мне нужно получить доступ к этим данным в разделе success для того чтобы использовать их повторно.

Comment: Продолжение:Сейчас в #but3 записывается просто таблица, конкретно в таблице есть имя+координаты gooogle map т.е.ltd и lat. Нужно мне теперь эти координаты в ajaxe увидеть (построчно) чтобы вывести маркеры на карту... А как их увидеть я не понимаю... Т.Е. они у меня выгружаются в виде таблицы в #but3 в результате выполнения кода $("#but3").html(data); А теперь мне по этой таблицы нужно пробежать и маркеры стандартной функцией расставить. Но бежать конкретно по самой html таблице не вариант, потом я же переделаю все на красивые divы.

Comment: Поэтому нужно в ajaxe увидеть данные типа $result или как результат запроса из БД получить чтобы с ним поработать в ajax(javascript)?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
success: function (data) {
  $("#but3").html(data);               
  var table = $('#mytable');
  table.each(function(idx, tr) {
    console.log(tr); // Доступ к строкам
    $(tr).each(function(idx, td) {
      console.log(td); // Доступ к ячейкам
    });
  });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую.

Вот пример работы

```
...
success: function (data) {
   $("#but3").html(data);
   var table = $(data); // создает объект jQuery
                        // дальше можно использовать привычные методы
   table.find('td');    // например найти все ячейки
}
...
```